# How to change ALL values in dataframe, df to ALL integers so as to pass it into function applyF1score properly?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, df as shown below. 
Data types of each column: order_id: int, actual: chr, predicted: chr.

[![df][1]][1]

I need to pass this dataframe, df into this function called applyF1score to get the mean f1 scores. For example if I pass an input called test defined like this to function applyF1score as defined below, I get proper f1 scores. But if I pass my df into the function, I can't get proper f1 scores. I just cannot find a way to convert all values in actual and predicted columns to all integers so that the applyF1score function can be properly applied. Please help.

```
test <- data.frame(order_id = c(1,2,3), 
             fact = c("100 200", "NA", "300 400"),
             predicted = c("100 300", "100", "300 400"))


F1Score <- function (fact, pred) {
       "%ni%" <- Negate("%in%")
       fact <- strsplit(fact, " ")
       fact <- fact[nzchar(fact)][[1]]

       pred <- strsplit(pred, " ")
       pred <- pred[nzchar(pred)][[1]]

       TP = sum(pred %in% fact)

       if(TP == 0) {
        return(0)
       }

      precision <- TP/length(pred)
      recall <- TP/length(fact)

     2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)
 }

applyF1Score <- function (df) {
    apply(df, 1, function (x) F1Score(x["fact"], x["predicted"]))
}
```

## Applying test to applyF1Score

```
test$f1 <- applyF1Score(test)
test
mean(test$f1)
```

Output:
 will be a dataframe with f1 scores

Comment: It is not clear what is not working here.  What answer are you expecting?  Your code does not do any arithmetic operations on `fact` or `pred`, so it does not matter that they are character variables.

Comment: When I pass input test into applyF1Score: I got:                            
  order_id    fact predicted  f1
1        1 100 200   100 300 0.5
2        2      NA       100 0.0
3        3 300 400   300 400 1.0                                                                               The mean of test$f1 = 0.5

Comment: But what about the actual data you mention that does not work?  You need to give us an error that we can reproduce, otherwise it is impossible to see what is going wrong.